# Function help for multiple Index searches - trying to round up or down within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I'm using an INDEX function to search the set of data on the left and match the score number to the applicable fruit. This is the formula in E2:E4:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

But what if my lookup is `75` and I want the formula to match the scores within a 10 point range? Can this be added into the current formula?

[image: Screenshot of data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `array` formula which will return the 65-74 range

> =IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$10=ROUND($E$1,-1),ROW($A$1:$A$10)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$10=ROUND($E$1,-1),ROW($A$1:$A$10)),ROW(1:1)),2))

Comment: Thanks irozak! This is getting me well on the way